# Column Contains Character From Another Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an easy way to have a condition "where column A has a character from a column B character"? Basically I have a column that has a letter for each day of the work week; MTWHF. I need to join two records where the days match, which is basically if letters match up in the strings.

```
----------------
| ID | MetDays |
----------------
| 1  | 'MWF'   |
| 2  | 'TH'    |
| 3  | 'M'     |
| 4  | 'T'     |
| 5  | 'WHF'   |
----------------
```

The SQL query would be something like;

```
SELECT MyTableA.ID AS IDa, MyTableB.ID AS IDb
FROM MyTable AS MyTableA
  JOIN MyTable AS MyTableB
    ON MyTableA.MetDays ???? MyTableB.MetDays
```

In this case, I would have successful `JOIN` between;

```
-------------
| IDa | IDb |
-------------
| 1   | 3   |
| 1   | 5   |
| 2   | 4   |
| 2   | 5   |
| (reverse) |
| 3   | 1   |
| 4   | 2   |
| 5   | 1   |
| 5   | 2   |
-------------
```

Comment: Have you tried using a table-valued function that splits that string out into rows, cross-applying it with each column, and joining on the results?

Comment: The correct answer is... *don't do this*.  You've basically denormalized your data... and this is exactly what happens when you denormalize data.  Your data is basically breaking [Database Design - First Normal Form: Each table cell should contain a single value](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html).  If you don't want to live in a world of insane SQL, normalize your data.  It's easier to take normalized data and return the first example than it is to do the reverse.

Comment: LOL, yeah, I know Erik. It's not our database but integrating a 3rd party database. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach splitting the days into 5 separate columns using `substring`:

```
select t1.id as IDa, t2.id as IDb
from mytable t1, mytable t2
where t1.id != t2.id and 
    (   (t1.metdays like '%' + substring(t2.metdays,1,1) + '%' and substring(t2.metdays,1,1) != '')
     or (t1.metdays like '%' + substring(t2.metdays,2,1) + '%' and substring(t2.metdays,2,1) != '')
     or (t1.metdays like '%' + substring(t2.metdays,3,1) + '%' and substring(t2.metdays,3,1) != '')
     or (t1.metdays like '%' + substring(t2.metdays,4,1) + '%' and substring(t2.metdays,4,1) != '')
     or (t1.metdays like '%' + substring(t2.metdays,5,1) + '%' and substring(t2.metdays,5,1) != '')
    )
order by t1.id, t2.id
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/WHE9169)

Comment: You can delete the bottom 5 conditions because every record will either be satisfied by the time it hits the 5th condition, or never satisfied. (self-join, so the bottom 5 conditions may as well be identical to the top 5)

Comment: @AaronDietz -- you are correct, I've had a long day and wasn't thinking :D

Comment: Happens to me all the time :)

Comment: I decided to go with this route with a slight modification remove the need for an empty string check; `t1.metdays like '%' + nullif(substring(t2.metdays,1,1), '') + '%'` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
create table MyTable ( ID int, MetDays varchar(5) )

insert into MyTable ( ID, MetDays ) values
( 1, 'MWF' ),
( 2, 'TH'  ),
( 3, 'M'   ),
( 4, 'T'   ),
( 5, 'WHF' )


;with 

  -- Create a table of the 5 characters.
  -- You might want to make this a permanent table.

  DayList as
  (       select 'M' as aDay 
    union select 'T' 
    union select 'W' 
    union select 'H' 
    union select 'F' ),

  -- Join MyTable with this list.
  -- The result will be one record for each letter in each row
  -- ID aDay
  --  1  M
  --  1  W
  --  1  F
  -- and so on

  MetDayList as
  ( select ID, aDay 
    from MyTable
    join DayList 
    on MyTable.MetDays like '%' + aDay + '%' )

  -- Self join this table

  select distinct A.ID as IDa, B.ID as IDb 
  from MetDayList A
  join MetDayList B 
  on A.ID <> B.ID
  and A.aDay=B.aDay 
  order by IDa, IDb
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach dispenses with `like` and uses bitmasks.

`CharIndex` is used to determine if a specific letter is in a string. It returns either the one-based position of the character or zero. `Sign` is used to fold all positive values to `1` while passing `0` through. With suitable multipliers (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) the matches are assembled into a bitmask with the least-significant-bit (LSB) being Monday, ... .

Bitwise arithmetic can be used on bitmasks. A bitwise AND will return all of the bits which are set (`1`) in both arguments. If there are no set bits in common then the result will be zero.

The process can be reversed to convert a bitmask to a string of day letters.

For improved performance the bitmasks can be stored in a persisted computed column. Note that indexing is not likely to be very helpful.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Meetings as Table ( Id Int Identity, MetDays VarChar(5) );
insert into @Meetings ( MetDays ) values
  ( 'MWF' ), ( 'TH' ), ( 'M' ), ( 'T' ), ( 'WHF' );
select * from @Meetings;

-- Play with the data.
declare @BusyDays as VarChar(5) = 'MWF'; -- I'm busy these days.
with
  BusyDays as ( -- Build a bitmask of the days that I'm busy.
    select @BusyDays as BusyDays,
      Sign( CharIndex( 'M', @BusyDays ) ) +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'T', @BusyDays ) ) * 2 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'W', @BusyDays ) ) * 4 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'H', @BusyDays ) ) * 8 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'F', @BusyDays ) ) * 16 as BusyDaysBitMask ),
  MetDays as ( -- Build a bitmask for the days each meeting occurs.
    select MetDays,
      Sign( CharIndex( 'M', MetDays ) ) +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'T', MetDays ) ) * 2 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'W', MetDays ) ) * 4 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'H', MetDays ) ) * 8 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'F', MetDays ) ) * 16 as MetDaysBitMask
      from @Meetings )
  select MD.MetDays, MD.MetDaysBitMask, BD.BusyDays, BD.BusyDaysBitMask,
    -- Bitwise AND of day bitmasks.  Zero means no days in common.
    MD.MetDaysBitMask & BD.BusyDaysBitMask as CollisionDaysBitMask,
    CD.CollisionDays
    from BusyDays as BD cross join
      MetDays as MD cross apply
      ( select -- Convert the collision bitmask back to a set of day letters.
          case when MD.MetDaysBitMask & BD.BusyDaysBitMask & 1 != 0 then 'M' else '' end +
          case when MD.MetDaysBitMask & BD.BusyDaysBitMask & 2 != 0 then 'T' else '' end +
          case when MD.MetDaysBitMask & BD.BusyDaysBitMask & 4 != 0 then 'W' else '' end +
          case when MD.MetDaysBitMask & BD.BusyDaysBitMask & 8 != 0 then 'H' else '' end +
          case when MD.MetDaysBitMask & BD.BusyDaysBitMask & 16 != 0 then 'F' else '' end as
            CollisionDays ) CD;
```

To compare meetings for days in common:

```
with
  MetDays as ( -- Build a bitmask for the days each meeting occurs.
    select MetDays,
      Sign( CharIndex( 'M', MetDays ) ) +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'T', MetDays ) ) * 2 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'W', MetDays ) ) * 4 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'H', MetDays ) ) * 8 +
      Sign( CharIndex( 'F', MetDays ) ) * 16 as MetDaysBitMask
      from @Meetings )
  select MDL.MetDays as 'MetDays Left', MDL.MetDaysBitMask as 'MetDaysBitMask Left',
    MDR.MetDays as 'MetDays Right', MDR.MetDaysBitMask as 'MetDaysBitMask Right',
    -- Bitwise AND of day bitmasks.  Zero means no days in common.
    MDL.MetDaysBitMask & MDR.MetDaysBitMask as CollisionDaysBitMask,
    CD.CollisionDays
    from MetDays as MDL cross join
      MetDays as MDR cross apply
      ( select -- Convert the collision bitmask back to a set of day letters.
          case when MDL.MetDaysBitMask & MDR.MetDaysBitMask & 1 != 0 then 'M' else '' end +
          case when MDL.MetDaysBitMask & MDR.MetDaysBitMask & 2 != 0 then 'T' else '' end +
          case when MDL.MetDaysBitMask & MDR.MetDaysBitMask & 4 != 0 then 'W' else '' end +
          case when MDL.MetDaysBitMask & MDR.MetDaysBitMask & 8 != 0 then 'H' else '' end +
          case when MDL.MetDaysBitMask & MDR.MetDaysBitMask & 16 != 0 then 'F' else '' end as
            CollisionDays ) CD;
```

If the letters will always be in the same order then a small lookup table can be used to map all 32 combinations of weekdays to the corresponding bitmask values. A somewhat larger table could be used if the order of letters is not guaranteed. That would replace all of the string manipulation and arithmetic with a table lookup in either direction.